# clone with jgit from gitlab

Tags: java, gitlab, jgit

I`m trying to use [jgit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit) library to work with git from my java code.
I can clone project with https protocol

```
Git.cloneRepository().setURI("https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook.git").setDirectory("jgit").call()
```

but we use gitlab, which allows only git protocol, and I get error for command like

```
Git.cloneRepository().setURI("git://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook").setDirectory("jgit").call()
```

Comment: Why GitLab allows only git? It can have https or ssh protocol as well. Is it because it is configured to limit to the git protocol only at your place?

Comment: You are right, this can be solution, thanks.
But is there a way to use git protocol?

Comment: git protocol (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol) is usually not recommended, because not efficient, and with no authentication or audit log.

Comment: That being said, sources like https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/719069680d483fa4e982d5d541d45e358d89ce5d/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/GitProtocolConstants.java seem to indicate JGit supports the Git protocol, but remember it does so on a dedicated port (9418) which might be blocked.